# How would the color of sand affect the color of glass?

Tags: geology, architecture

So, I know that there are naturally occurring beaches that are various 'odd' colors like pink, black, green, and orange and I was wondering if the color of this sand would have any effects on the color of glass made from it. Like would the buildings nearby have glass tinged pink or green or some other color? Or would the process of making the glass cause the color to be removed?

Comment: As phrased, I think you may get a better answer in [arts&crafts.se](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/). Currently this question doesn't have much of a worldbuilding component.

Comment: off-topic. anyway, just start reading this article about colored glass https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_coloring_and_color_marking

Comment: On topic, but deserves downvotes for lack of research.

Comment: @Aify What you said. lack of preliminary research is the main problem.

Comment: @Aify I did do some research before I asked my question but I was on my lunch break so I didn't have a lot of time to do it in. As you say I should have spent more time looking before I asked it, I apologize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Metal oxides are what causes the color in most colored glass. If your sand is colored, the color of the glass will depend on what is causing the color in the sand.

The following components in your mixture will cause different colors:

- Cobalt Oxide: blue-violet
- Cadmium Sulfide: yellow
- Gold Chloride: red
- Antimony Oxide: white
- Sulfur: yellow-amber
- Uranium Oxide: fluorescent yellow, green
- Chromic Oxide: emerald green

In other words, if your sand is pink due to some other material, and your sand composition doesn't include stuff like the ones listed above, your glass is probably NOT going to be colored.

Comment: "In other words, if your sand is pink due to some other material, and your sand composition doesn't include stuff like the ones listed above, your **sand** is probably NOT going to be colored." do you not mean *glass*?

Answer (score 1):

Glass is made from quartz sand, mixed with sodium and calcium carbonates. Quartz sand is the most common sand: it's what you have in the Sahara, most beaches, etc. It's yellow-white.

Green sand (such as olivine sand in Hawaii), black sand (heavy minerals such as magnetite) and other kinds of "sands" are not quartz sand, therefore they are not suitable to make glass.

So when you're asking:

> I was wondering if the color of this sand would have any effects on the color of glass made from it.

The answer is no, because you cannot make glass from these kinds of sands.